# How to use CJK environment in .dtx documentation?

Tags: cjk, dtx

This is my `a.dtx` file, which doesn't compile:

```
% \GetFileInfo{a.dtx}
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{a.dtx}
%</driver>
%<class>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%<class>\ProvidesClass{a}
%<*class>
[00.00.0000 0.0.0 a]
%</class>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{a.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi

% \StopEventually{}
% \begin{macro}{\foo}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
你好
\end{CJK}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \Finale
```

The problem is in the `CJK` environment. However, this document compiles:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
你好
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the example to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
你好
\end{CJK}
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

whch gives

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character 你 (U+4F60)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

The problem is that `\usepackage{CJKutf8}` is read verbatim and typeset as text so does not set up the characters.

You can not simply make the CJK characters non-special as for example `%` or `\`  are handled in `verbatim` (or `macrocode`) as they need to be active to handle decoding UTF8.

The simplest solution would be to typeset using lualatex or xelatex when the chinese charaters can be handled as simple characters just like `hello`

If pdftex is a requirement, something will be possible ...

eg this works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
你好
\end{CJK}
\end{verbatim}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would it look in `.dtx`?

Comment: @yegor256 can you not use luatex ?? `macrocode` parses the text byte-by-byte for indexing, doing that while decoding utf-8 looks tricky and all the complication goes if you use a unicode tex.

Comment: I don't use luatex. I use `pdflatex`.

Comment: @yegor256 but why? pdftex comes from an era when using an accented e was "exotic" it is still very good at European scripts and it is possible in _very_ restricted ways to make _something_ work for Asian scripts, but the contortions it has to do to  typeset even a single CJK character mean adding any other processing on top is needlessly difficult compared to luatex or xetex where cjk characters are just normal letters as easy as abc. pdftex fonts have at most 256 characters and really that makes no sense for Chinese.

Comment: I may switch to xetex easily, but what about users of my package? They may have pdftex and my package will break when they try to install it. Right?

Comment: @yegor256 almost  no users are ever going to typeset the documentation. I can't recall last time I did that  for a texlive package. They just go `texdoc yegor` and get the pdf in the distribution, which is the pdf you put on ctan.